# Unable to extend from a file that has no public class

Tags: java

Test.java and B.java are in default package.

File Test.java(as we can give any name for a file that has no public class) contains:

```
class A{}
```

File B.java contains:

```
class B extends A{}
```

If I compile B.java it gives an error saying:

```
B.java:1: error: cannot find symbol    
class B extends A{   
                ^
symbol: class A
1 error
```

What is the problem with the code? Please help me out!

Answer (score 2):

The compiler will look for class `A` in the same file as where it is mentioned (in this case `B.java`). After that it will look for it in the classpath and `import` list. After that it will look for it in the file `A.java` within the same package, this file doesn't exist. It finds it nowhere so... `cannot find symbol`.

Do what @Vikdor recommended: compile `Test.java` first.

Comment: i came to know how compiler searches for a class. Thanks:)

Answer (score 2):

You should compile `Test.java` for `A.class` to be created. Then you should try to compile `B.java` and the compiler will find `A.class` in the current directory which is the default `CLASSPATH`.

```
C:\Temp\test>dir
 Volume in drive C is OSDisk
 Volume Serial Number is 1E37-6273

 Directory of C:\Temp\test

09/23/2012  10:48 PM    <DIR>          .
09/23/2012  10:48 PM    <DIR>          ..
09/23/2012  10:47 PM               100 B.java
09/23/2012  10:47 PM                68 Test.java
               2 File(s)            168 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  171,760,668,672 bytes free

C:\Temp\test>type Test.java
class A
{
    static {
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}
C:\Temp\test>Type B.java
class B extends A
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        new B();
    }
}
C:\Temp\test>javac Test.java

C:\Temp\test>dir
 Volume in drive C is OSDisk
 Volume Serial Number is 1E37-6273

 Directory of C:\Temp\test

09/23/2012  10:49 PM    <DIR>          .
09/23/2012  10:49 PM    <DIR>          ..
09/23/2012  10:49 PM               375 A.class
09/23/2012  10:47 PM               100 B.java
09/23/2012  10:47 PM                68 Test.java
               3 File(s)            543 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  171,760,668,672 bytes free

C:\Temp\test>javac B.java

C:\Temp\test>java B
A

C:\Temp\test>
```

Comment: can you elaborate `this is not working`? Can you check if A.class file is present in the same directory as B.java that is trying to extend A defined in a file other than A.java and that file has already been compiled?

Comment: whatever u r saying,  i did like that, but it gives same error

Comment: @Ravindrabagale, Please see the update to my answer and let me know if you are doing anything different.

Comment: @Ravindrabagale, not sure what is different in your set up. It should just work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you compile Test.java first, there will be an A.class file. If you don't then the compiler doesn't know how to find class A (because it only knows to look for A.class or A.java).

Answer (score 0):

```
   It's Working na..............

  //Test.java

   class A   

  {

  public static void main(String arg[])

    {

        System.out.println("A");

    }

 }

 //B.java

public class B extends A

{

    public static void main(String arg[])

    {

        System.out.println("B");

    }

 }
```

Comment: First You must Compile Super Class after that only u hav to compile sub classes. Just compile like javac *.java. it takecare of evry thing.....

Answer (score 0):

**Create class A**

`class A{}`

**Create class B**

`class B extends A{}`

**Now Do take of these :**

**1.** `class A` and `class B` should be in the **Same Package**, as `class A` has a `default access modifier`, so **only package level access** is granted.

**2. Compile** `class A` **first**, then compile `class B`.